# Xlsxwriter display different types of data on chart

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I'm creating a program to gather data from google analytics and append the data to an excel sheet. I have everything displaying correctly except for the charts displaying Time and Percentage Values

In the Xlsxwriter chart documentation it doesn't specify clearly what to do or if there is even anything to do.

```
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type':'line'})
chart.set_chartarea({'border': {'none': True}})
chart.set_legend({'position': 'none'})
chart.add_series({'values':'$B$48:$B$59', 'categories': '=\$A$48:A$59'})

worksheet.insert_chart('A18', chart)
```

This is the Data being Used to create the chart

[image: data columns]

The program does not realize what type of data to display and is resulting in this:

[image: problem chart]

My goal is to have the program understand I'm trying to graph time stamp data (4:38) and be able to display it on the chart in this example from a customized excel sheet

[image: correct chart]

Comment: There isn’t enough information here to debug the issue. Can you add sample data and turn the sample code into a working example.

Comment: @jmcnamara, I updated the question and I hope this will help everyone better understand the problem

Comment: Updating the text without updating the code doesn’t help. If you post a small working program that demonstrates the issue then people can run it, see what the issue is, and advise you on a fix.

Comment: @jmcnamara, I appreciate your willingness to help. Could I get in contact with you so I can further explain my problem, and give you an example?

Comment: It would be best to answer the question here so someone else with a similar problem can find the answer. The issue is almost certainly with the data being plotted and that is the part that is missing from the question.

Comment: @jmcnamara Updated. I hope this is what you mean

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Here is a working example based on (some of) your data:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Create a new Chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Write some data to add to plot on the chart.
data = [
    ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN'],
    [2.52,  4.45,   2.58, 2.04,  1.13,  2.46],
    [2.53,  2.05,   2.47, 3.00,  2.56,  1.53],
]

worksheet.write_column('A1', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B1', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C1', data[2])

# Configure the charts. In simplest case we just add some data series.
chart.add_series({
    'categories': ['Sheet1', 0, 0, 5, 0],
    'values':     ['Sheet1', 0, 1, 5, 1],
})

chart.add_series({
    'categories': ['Sheet1', 0, 0, 5, 0],
    'values':     ['Sheet1', 0, 2, 5, 2],
})


# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('E2', chart)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

If the data isn't being plotted, in your case, it may be that the data isn't numeric.